# Is there any npm module to format number in Indian currency?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I'm working on a Shopping cart project using NodeJs with MongoDB as backend.

I have already grab the item total to the checkout page, but I need the figure to be displayed using commas as each 3 digit passing from left side.

for example. 70000 should be printed as 70,000 and 1400000 should be printed as 1,400,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` works well for most cases. You can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```
var number = 3500;

console.log(number.toLocaleString());
// Displays "3,500" if in U.S. English locale
```

Comment: Thank you:) It's working....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Numeral.js: http://numeraljs.com/ This package handles numbers nicely.